# Ubuntu install hangs 'Timed out for waiting the udev queue being empty'

Tags: boot, udev

Every time I try to install Ubuntu it hangs and after a while Ubuntu install hangs 'Timed out for waiting the udev queue being empty' appears on screen twice. I'm using Rufus to write Ubuntu 23.04 to an USB stick. This happens only with my HP pavilion PC. This also happens with all other Linux distributions I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

a work around i found was to hold shift during boot, press e and add noapic nomodeset to the boot parameters.

Comment: Isn'it `noacpi` instead of `noapic`?

Comment: I believe they meant noapic meaning to disable the enhanced interrupt controller.